# Searching for an unknown IP using FINDSTR

Tags: regex, windows, command-line, findstr

I have text files with hundreds of entries like those below. They mostly come in pairs of 2 IPs. Sometimes they come as 3 IPs. I am trying to find that third IP that is always in the middle of the stack (syntax below). There are maximum 3 different IPs in each file at all times. It is possible that some text files won’t have that middle IP (its occurrence is quite rare). How do I write the search command to find the middle IP from mentioned stacks if there is one in the text file? OS: Win7.

Text file sample syntax:

```
- saving IP addresses

* 192.168.1.1

* 111.111.222.222

- over

- saving IP addresses

* 192.168.1.1

* 11.123.11.123

* 111.111.222.222

- over

- saving IP addresses

* 192.168.1.1

* 111.111.222.222

- over
```

I have tried `findstr \-.*\*.*\*.*\- pathtofile.txt` This should return the block of 3 IPs if there is such block in the file but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! I think it would make your post more readable if you put the sample text file inside of a code block, but I'm not sure how it's meant to be formatted. Can you [edit] to make that change? Also, please add any commands you've tried as it shows effort and helps us understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your real file isn't double-spaced like your sample, the following will output the first line (saving...) and line number of matching blocks. Your real problem is `findstr` will only output one line even if you are matching across lines, so you will never get the whole block output. You need a better tool.

Note: I am using the JPSoft Take Command escape character to put in CR and LF, but you can create them in real batch files as well, though it isn't easy.

```
findstr /n /R saving.*^r^n.*\..*\..*\..*^r^n.*\..*\..*\..*^r^n.*\..*\..*\..*^r^n sampleIPinput.txt
```